# How to use Defaultabcontroller with Provider in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Condition don't work  with StatelessWidget and Provider in Flutter,

Hopefully, I need that FloatingActionButton show up in specific tab but current code does not work properly. FloatingActionButton work in all tab.

I tried to debug and found index value is reflected but the Button does not disappear when changing tab.

```
   return DefaultTabController(

      length: 3,
      initialIndex: 0,

      child: ChangeNotifierProvider<MainModel>(

        create: (_) => MainModel()..getWorkoutListRealtime(),

        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("Workout at home"),
            actions: [
              Consumer<MainModel>(builder: (context, model, child) {
                final isActive = model.checkShouldActiveCompleteButton();

                return FlatButton(
                  onPressed: isActive
                      ? () async {
                    await model.deleteCheckedItems();
                  }
                      : null,
                  child: Text(
                    '削除',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color:
                      isActive ? Colors.white : Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              })
            ],
            bottom: TabBar(
              tabs: [
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_transit)),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_bike)),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(

            children: [
              Consumer<MainModel>(builder: (context, model, child) {

            

                ------------------------------------------------------------------

              Consumer<MainModel>(builder: (context, model, child) {

                return SimpleDatumLegend.withSampleData(model);

              }),

              CountdownTimer(),

            ],
          ),

          floatingActionButton:
          Consumer<MainModel>(builder: (context, model, child) {

             final index = DefaultTabController.of(context).index;



            return index == 1

            ? FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                await Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => AddPage(model),
                    fullscreenDialog: true,
                  ),
                );
              },
              child: Icon(Icons.touch_app),
            )

            : SizedBox.shrink();
          }),
```

I use DefaultTabController because I use Stateless widget and Provider function.